# Mocking an observable in angular

Tags: angular

I am writing a test using Jasmine in angular. I have mocked a promise but now need to mock the Observable. If you see the code below, tierhistory is the promise. I have set it by declaring in the providers section

```
tierHistory: () => Promise.resolve(mocKTierHistory)
```

My obserable is getPersonNote. When I try it like done below get compile error

```
 getPersonNote: () =>  Observable.subscribe( value => mockPersonNote ),
```

Could you tell me how do I do it

```
export class PersonNote {
  id: number;
  personId: number;
  note: string;
  authorName: string;
  fileName: string;
  mimeType: string;
  alias: string;
}

export class TierHistory {
  tierId: number;
  tierName: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
}
```

TestComponent

```
describe('RepresentativeDetailComponent', () => {
  let component: RepresentativeDetailComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RepresentativeDetailComponent>;
  let supervisorPermission = false;
  let personNotesPermission = false;

  const mockUserService: UserService = <UserService>{
    getCurrentUser: () => MockUsers.user4,
    getPerson(id: number) {},
    getPersonUpline(id: number) {},
    getPersonNote(id: number) {}
  };

  const mocKTierHistory = [
    <TierHistory>{ 'tierId': 1, 'tierName': 'Representative', 'startDate': '2009-05-29T00:00:00', 'endDate': '2029-06-30T00:00:00' },
    <TierHistory>{ 'tierId': 2, 'tierName': 'Team Leader', 'startDate': '2009-06-30T00:00:00', 'endDate': '2009-12-01T00:00:00' }
  ];


  const mockPersonNote = [
    <PersonNote>{ 'id': 1, 'personId': 100, 'note': 'This is testnote1', 'authorName': 'Ranjit Menon', 'fileName': 'test.pdf', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'alias': 'test.pdf' },
    <PersonNote>{ 'id': 2, 'personId': 101, 'note': 'This is testnote2', 'authorName': 'Mr x', 'fileName': 'test.pdf', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'alias': 'test1.pdf' },
  ];

  const mockRoute = { params: of({ id: 123 }), snapshot: {} };
  function setupComponent() {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RepresentativeDetailComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }

  configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        FontAwesomeModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
      ],
      declarations: [
        RepresentativeDetailComponent,
        MockComponent(RecruiterPanelComponent),
        MockComponent(PersonPanelComponent),
        MockComponent(ExamSummaryComponent)
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: UserService, useValue: mockUserService },
        { provide: AppConfigService, useClass: MockAppConfigService },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockRoute },
        { provide: UserService,
          useFactory: () => new Mock<UserService>({
            getPersonNote: () =>  Observable.subscribe( value => mockPersonNote ),
            }
          ).Object
        },

        { provide: UserManagementService,
          useFactory: () => new Mock<UserManagementService>({
            tierHistory: () => Promise.resolve(mocKTierHistory),
            }
          ).Object
        },
        { provide: DxTemplateHost }
      ]
    });
  });


  it('should call getTierHistory when tab selected', fakeAsync(() => {
    const event = {
      component: null,
      element: null,
      event: null,
      itemData: { id: 1, text: 'Tier History', component: 'tierHistory' },
      itemElement: null,
      itemIndex: 0
    };
    setupComponent();
    component.selectTab(event);
    expect(component['userManagementService'].tierHistory).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));


  it('should call getPersonNotes when tab selected', fakeAsync(() => {
    const event = {
      component: null,
      element: null,
      event: null,
      itemData: { id: 3, text: 'Notes', component: 'getPersonNote' },
      itemElement: null,
      itemIndex: 0
    };
    setupComponent();
    component.selectTab(event);
    expect(component['userService'].getPersonNote).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it('should set personNotesPermission to FALSE if user doesnt have permission ViewNotes', fakeAsync(() => {
    setupComponent();
    const myUser = MockUsers.user1.permissions.includes('ViewNotes');
    if (!myUser) {
      personNotesPermission = false;
      expect(personNotesPermission).toBeFalsy();
    }
  }));

  it('should set personNotesPermission to TRUE if user doesnt have permission ViewNotes', fakeAsync(() => {
    setupComponent();
    const myUser = MockUsers.user1.permissions.includes('ViewNotes');
    if (!myUser) {
      personNotesPermission = true;
      expect(personNotesPermission).toBeTruthy();
    }
  }));



});
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an observable that always emits a given value? If so, do it as you're already doing it to provide parameters in your route: using `of(value)`.

Comment: I think i haven't understood you properly. I want to use mockPersonNote data as an observable. I am getting a compile error at the moment doing Observable.Subscribe. It doesn't allow me to do Observable.of(mockPersonNote) for instance

Comment: You shouldn't use `Observable.of(mockPersonNote) `. You should use what you're already using to create an observble for the parameters of your route, and that I also wrote in my previous comment: `of(mockPersonNote)`. `of()`is a function, not a static method of Observable. The documentation is your friend. Don't try random things. Read carefully.